# use windows' shell from php

Tags: php, windows, shell, command

I'm building a website that needs some ressources from a software in windows. So, I need to run windows' shell from notepad++ using php. Are there any php scripts to execute commands from windows' shell?

Comment: dont know what you would like todo .... take a look at exec() system() shell_exec() functions .. more infos at php.net

Comment: you cant just run php script from notepad. but on php you can call http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php `shell_exec`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function exec() - do note that there are some bugs with it (If a script (with the exec command) is loaded more than once by the same user at the same time the server will freeze.)

A solution for this is found in the PHP manual:

```
<?php

session_write_close();
exec($cmd);
session_start();

?>
```